# I want to add a user in CIVI using drupal

Tags: user

I would like to create a user profile without administration privileges but can add people to our account. For example we have 3 employees, I want them to have access to the clients we serve but not be able to make administrative changes. I am able to add a user profile for drupal but not add it for civi.

Comment: Have a look at the CiviCRM permissions that Drupal offers via the People > Permissions screen

Answer (score 1):

That is possible. The way I would recommend going about this is making a new role in Drupal for your staff.  People -> Roles -> Add role

[image: add role]

After adding the role, you can then navigate to People -> Permissions and change settings as you wish! You can set specific access to CiviCRM with certain permissions granted, while others (more admin-level permissions) remain hidden from them. Then, simply set their drupal role to be the newly created role.

[image: permissions]